# Replace router on the stick

Tags: router

Configuration that I need to replace is:

Cisco 1841 (Connected to the internet via ISP (ethernet), Point to point via 2 T1 to another location, backup vpn to another 1841 if PTP fails, Eigrp routing, firewall features, Router on the stick)

Core switch Cisco 2960 (Data, Voice, Mgmt vlans, connected to the rest of the network)

We upgraded ISP to 100Mb/s and it looks like Cisco 1841 can't handle it. I am getting 35 Mb/s download.

What will be best way to replace this? I am thinking to have some decent firewall connected to the internet which will be connected to the core layer 3 switch (for Vlan routing) and then have router connected to the core switch to provide PTP connection and VPN if PTP fails.

Please let me know what do you think,
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your question.  At this time, there isn't enough information to help you.  Please consider adding [more information](http://tinyurl.com/ne-checklist/) to the question; also try not to assume what the solution to your problem is.  You may find that the solution to your problem is not what you're assuming it is.

Comment: A good start to improving this question would be the number of users you're supporting.

Comment: Sorry guys. There is around 100 users at the site. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you provided we can only make a wild guess...
How many users in your site?
You may want to replace the 1841 according to this https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2014551
There are tables on the Cisco website that are publicly available for sizing up better routers.

I would suggest replacing the 2960 with a 3750x (preferable) or 3560 switch and enable ip routing on the new switch. 
Remove the 2960, then move all of your vlans, acls and management configs to the new switch.
Create a point to point between the new switch and your router, enable a routing protocol (i.e. ospf) between your router and the new switch.
Your new router can now dedicate more cpu cycles to routing ip traffic, QoS, vpn and other services you would like to enable.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should also secure the router and switches. For a start, check out this ios template on this site http://www.team-cymru.org/ReadingRoom/Templates/